# Is it possible to create index for a temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I want to apply indexing on a temporary table which is first created and then read many times. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can and in fact recommended to make your programm perform well.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible de create indexes on a temporary table.